# Chromedriver versions are labelled differently in chromium website and maven repository. Which one to consider for chromedriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I see *chromedriver* is available on https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/ and also on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver.
However the versions are different in both cases.

In chromium website, it is mentioned as **Current stable release: ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30**

In maven repository, it is mentioned as **4.0.0-alpha-6 as latest artifact.**

**Question:** What is the difference between both and which one should be included as a project dependency for chromedriver.exe ? I am using a *selenium java testng* project.

Comment: The former are chromedriver versions, the latter are selenium versions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Are both same ?

Comment: They are clearly different numbers! Basically you have Chrome <-> Chromedriver <-> Selenium Chrome Driver <-> Selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are partially correct as they are different.

The [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) you see at [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) is the executable binary which we use most commonly as in:

- Java:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  ```
- Python:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  ```

Where as the installation of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) libraries for Selenium-Java clients can be done using [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) as well just by adding the `selenium-java` dependency in your project `pom.xml` which would support running your automation project with all Selenium supported browsers:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.X</version>
</dependency>
```

But if you want to run tests only in a specific browser, e.g. ***Chrome***, you can add the *Chrome* specific dependency in the project `pom.xml` file as follows:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
</dependency>
```

The artifacts within [Selenium Chrome Driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver) is the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) bindings specifically for the *ChromeDriver* and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) combo.

Comment: Is there any dependency available in maven repository to pull chromedriver.exe to avoid manual download and setting it’s path in the code? Such dependency is available as Selenium Chrome driver in nuget package manager for C# tests that gets chromedriver.exe and copies to bin folder during build.

Comment: I see one maven dependency - WebDriverManager from bonigarcia which does it or use driver-binary-downloader maven plugin from Adresco. Are there any latest ways or just follow one among these ?

Comment: @newuser That's right, _chromedriver.exe to avoid manual download_ WebDriverManager from bonigarcia is the solution. But it does have some side effects which is again another big discussion.

Answer (score 1):

To understand these we need to first understand following:

1. **ChromeDriver** is a standalone server that implements the W3C WebDriver standard.
   https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html is location of executables from google.
2. **WebDriver** is an open source tool for automated testing of webapps across many browsers. It provides capabilities for navigating to web pages, user input, JavaScript execution, and more.
   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver is location of mvn dependences to interact with ChromeDriver executable. So have **selenium-chrome-driver** ***ChromeDriver*** class
   : A WebDriver implementation that controls a Chrome browser running on the local machine.

Some more good read links:

- What we have in **selenium-chrome-driver** https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/4.7.2/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html
- WebDriver commands https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/chromedriver_status.md
- Change logs for JAVA in selenium versions https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG